# How can you reach the same level of efficiency using gdb as you do with a visual debugger?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I know this is like heresy, but I simply can't see how using gdb can be more efficient, in daily debug use (not advanced dumping and logging debug), than a visual debugger.

I come from a background of .Net (Love the environment hate the mentality) and over the past coupld of years moved to PHP & C++.
I am now developing a project in C++, using Eclipse, and hate how heavy the editor is, so I've moved to Textmate.
But debugging is so uncomfortable.
I'm using gdb, but miss visual debug, which is so much easier and efficient.

And yet, every one says - Learn to use gdb properly!
So I'm asking- how do I use gdb properly & efficiently?

Comment: Community wiki? Not really a *question*. It's like asking "How do I write good programs?"

Comment: Very interesting question.  I'm a regular user of VisualStudio and Xcode.  Xcode's visual debugging is very poor and I usually find myself dropping to the gdb console in it to get anything done.  I'd like to hear of useful hints.  Up to now almost all respondents have just given suggestions of visual wrappers for gdb rather than tips for how to use it more effectively.

Comment: What, exactly, is the "mentality" of .NET?

Comment: Could you give some examples of things you find easy in a visual debugger and hard in gdb?

Comment: I would argue that this is not possible.

Comment: @Bill - I think the hardest thing in command line is gaining context... its much easier to see how the current line relates to other lines and data around you in a visual debugger.

Comment: @Che: I agree (that's why I said I don't think it's possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for me, I always use [gdb's TUI mode](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI.html). From gdb manual:

> The gdb Text User Interface (TUI) is a
>   terminal interface which uses the
>   curses library to show the source
>   file, the assembly output, the program
>   registers and gdb commands in separate
>   text windows. The TUI mode is
>   supported only on platforms where a
>   suitable version of the curses library
>   is available.

It brings some visual debugging to gdb and it's enough for me. I usually start gdb in regular command line mode, watch backtraces and set breakpoints in it. When I want to look at source code I swith to TUI mode with key binding C-x C-a and switch back to look backtraces for example. This is built-in ready to use feature of gdb. You need not any additional software like KDevelop or Emacs to use it.

Answer (score 6):

You could use gdb with an IDE like **KDevelop**. It has an visual interface so that helps.
Or **GDB with Emacs**, It does nearly everything fancy graphical debuggers can do and with ease.

Just to add, You can have a look at [**this**](http://blog.ksplice.com/2011/01/8-gdb-tricks/) article. It tells about some nice tricks.

Answer (score 3):

You could try qt-creatror, which has also nice and easy GDB visual interface.

Answer (score 2):

What about [DDD](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/) ?

Comment: DDD definitely works. Too bad is seems to be abandoned. It's GUI can certainly use some love (syntax highlighting anyone?)

Comment: @nimrodm: I never realized it was abandoned. It still works for my debugging needs. But maybe I will try Nemiver one day..

Answer (score 0):

I use netbeans for C++. It integrates with gdb and gives you visual debugging. It's not as nice as Visual Studio but it's close. It's cleaner and lighter than Eclipse. It wasn't easy to get everything set up on Windows though. I can provide some pointers there if you need them

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps gdb is even more efficient. It can make use of core dumps when debugging hard to reproduce bugs like peculiar dead locks. It can also debug running processes. Other features like conditional breakpoints, and more recently developed reverse execution also make gdb stand out.

Disclaimer: I don't use a visual debugger, and I am not very sure if they support the above.

Comment: Yep, you get all that in a good visual debugger. VisualStudio has all that: core dumps, attach to process, conditional breakpoints and tracepoints, etc.

Comment: @the_mandrill: how about reverse execution? This is something new in gdb, do other debuggers have these?

Comment: Not in VS2008, but I think VS2010 may have it.  Things that a good (integrated) visual debugger has that gdb doesn't: 

 - Source navigation including proper jump to definition/declaration (ie not just tag tables) and macro
 - Edit and continue
 - Tooltips to show variable values in source

Comment: @the_mandrill: VS2010 has it for managed code (and calls the feature "Intellitrace") It's not available for native code, however.